# How to edit boot options Ubuntu 20.04 EFI?

Tags: boot, 20.04, system-installation, uefi

Booting Ubuntu 20.04 with BIOS it is possible to "cancel" the boot in the graphical using `<esc>` and the boot options will be available in the bottom of the screen.
Example: `Boot Options: initrd=/casper/initrd quiet ---`

How to I edit *boot options* in the same way as described above using Ubuntu 20.04 EFI?

Comment: With BIOS, it is the shift key to get grub menu. With UEFI, you have to press escape right after UEFI/BIOS screen but before grub menu would normally appear. If UEFI fast boot on, you may not have time to press any key. Then in grub menu are keys to get to command line or edit grub boot stanza. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2